# How can i change eclipse code completion settings?

Tags: java, eclipse

Sorry about unclear title, i'm new in Java and Eclipse. Here is my problem I have been using `Visual Studio` for a long time, and in Visual studio, assume i have a variable named `sampleText`, when i type `"samp"` or something like that intellisense shows up and when i press `TAB` it write sampleText, but to do the same thing in ecplise i have to press `Enter`, and it's not so cool,i want to change this option, i mean when i press `TAB` i want it to write selected value. How can i do that ?

Comment: Please change the title to something like Eclipse shortcuts it is confusing.....

Comment: No, the title is good .. the feature is configurable under Content assist; shorcuts are keyboard shortcuts, which would be confusing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to change that behavior. I believe it is standard behavior in SWT to select items in lists with ENTER.

As a side note.
You can select Visual Studio key bindings in

> Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys
>
> Change Scheme to Microsoft Visual Studio.

It won't help you with your current problem but it might help you transition to Eclipse.

Comment: The problem is, that TAB is bound to the selection of items within SWT, the tab order. The tab order is configurable to determine the order of element (Control) selections in another composite Control. To change this behaviour would mean a significant change of user interface behaviour.